# how to override storage class methods 'Storage::has()' and 'Storage::get()' in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, overriding, storage

I need to extend the storage class methods so i can have my own definition of has() and get() methods, as i need to perform additional checks too, because when i use S3, the has() method errors out when thee connection is poor or has some other server related issue.

```
class Storage extends \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemManager
{
    public function has($file){
       // custom definition
    }

}
```

I tried making a class and extending the storage facade but, im getting this error

```
[BadMethodCallException]                                          
  Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::isDeferred
```

is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the accessor type along with the binding of app service binding, if you want to override/extend any method or make your custom methods.

```
class Storage extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage {  

  protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {

    return 'filesystem'; // This one is fine
  }
}
```

and in your appserviceprovider.php

```
$this->app->bind('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class', function ($app) {
   return new MyNamespace\Storage());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The storage class is a Facade. You will need to use the container binding. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container

```
$this->app->bind('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class', function ($app) {
     return new MyNamespace\Storage());
});
```

This will allow you to create your own implementations as you have done.

Comment: i didnt register this in my service provider class, thanks a ton, this worked

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Would you mind marking the answer as correct please :)

Comment: i tried it, but my low reputation in here didn't allow that. i will mark it once i gain some reputation around here